# How do I loop models over dataframes?

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I have 4 datasets (dat, dat2, dat3, dat4) and I want to construct multiple linear regressions of all of them. In the end, I need a table to compare the models according to RMSE, r², RPD and Mean Error. The code I'm using is able to do for univariate models, for each feature in each data set. Here it goes:

```
dat <- structure(list(TILLER1 = c(43, 23, 46, 30, 30, 45), 
                      LAI1 = c(3.545, 1.5, 1.76, 1.92, 1.36, 1.27), 
                      CHLOR1 = c(447.2, 432.8, 457.6, 449, 486.8, 455), 
                      HEIGHT1 = c(34.8, 31.5, 26.1, 26, 40.5, 35.2 ), 
                      DIAM1 = c(25.23, 23.9, 21.97, 20.99, 23.92, 24.01), 
                      NDRE1 = c(0.2579, 0.1911, 0.1643, 0.2072, 0.2233, 0.2009), 
                      NDVI1 = c(0.6495, 0.4502, 0.3643, 0.4904, 0.5625, 0.4725), 
                      TCH = c(127.55, 142.33, 127.19, 86.64, 144.36, 155.95)), 
                      .Names = c("TILLER1", "LAI1", "CHLOR1", "HEIGHT1", "DIAM1", "NDRE1", "NDVI1", "TCH"), 
                      row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

 ### RMSE
 rmse <- function(error)
 {
   sqrt(mean(error^2))
 }

 # tabel of R², Erro médio, RMSE and RPD
 tabel = NULL
 for (i in 3:(ncol(dat)-1)) {

   ## Train control
   fitControl <- trainControl (
     method = "repeatedcv",
     number = 10,
     savePredictions = "final")

   ## Creating all models
   set.seed(62433)
   reg = train(TCH ~ ., data = dat[, c(i, which(colnames(dat) == "TCH"))], 
          method = 'lm', 
          trControl = fitControl, 
          verbose = TRUE,
          importance = TRUE)

   mean.error = mean(dat$TCH - data.frame(reg$pred$pred)[, 1])

   rpd = sd(dat[, which(colnames(dat) == "TCH")][[1]]) / rmse(residuals(reg))

   tmp = data.frame(variable = names(dat[,i]), r2 = summary(reg)$r.squared, 
               mean_error = mean.error, rmse = rmse(residuals(reg)), rpd = rpd)

   if (is.null(tabel)) {
     tabel = tmp
   } else {
     tabel = rbind(tabel, tmp)
   }

 }

 tabel
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to achieve for this question? Do you want a way to loop over multiple data frames to do regressions? If so, this can be done quite easily with either `for`-loops or `lapply`.

Comment: I have 4 datasets. I want to construct multiple linear regressions of all. All of them have the same Y variable. As an output, I would like to have a table with the following columns: Dataset, R², Mean Error, RMSE and RPD.

Comment: Do all models use the same predictors? Also, which packages do you use? `caret`?

Comment: I'm using caret. Every dataset has the same attributes, but for different evaluations. I have several atributes: i.e. tiller1, tiller2 tiller3, tiller4 and LAI1, LAI2 etc... so in the end my dataset dat has tiller1, lai1 etc and dat2 has tiller2, lai2 and so on.

Comment: The easiest would be to wrap the `tabel` part of your code in a function with `dat` as the input, `lapply` it over a list of your dataframes, and then use something like `do.call(cbind, tabellist)` to create the combined `tabel`. To be more specific with help, I would need you to provide some example data, like with `dput(head(dat))`.

Comment: > head(dat1)
  TILLER1  LAI1 CHLOR1 HEIGHT1 DIAM1  NDRE1  NDVI1    TCH
1      43 3.545  447.2    34.8 25.23 0.2579 0.6495 127.55
2      23 1.500  432.8    31.5 23.90 0.1911 0.4502 142.33
3      46 1.760  457.6    26.1 21.97 0.1643 0.3643 127.19
4      30 1.920  449.0    26.0 20.99 0.2072 0.4904  86.64
5      30 1.360  486.8    40.5 23.92 0.2233 0.5625 144.36
6      45 1.270  455.0    35.2 24.01 0.2009 0.4725 155.95

Comment: Please use `dput()` and edit the output into your question, instead of using a comment.

Comment: structure(list(TILLER1 = c(43, 23, 46, 30, 30, 45), LAI1 = c(3.545, 
1.5, 1.76, 1.92, 1.36, 1.27), CHLOR1 = c(447.2, 432.8, 457.6, 
449, 486.8, 455), HEIGHT1 = c(34.8, 31.5, 26.1, 26, 40.5, 35.2
), DIAM1 = c(25.23, 23.9, 21.97, 20.99, 23.92, 24.01), NDRE1 = c(0.2579, 
0.1911, 0.1643, 0.2072, 0.2233, 0.2009), NDVI1 = c(0.6495, 0.4502, 
0.3643, 0.4904, 0.5625, 0.4725), TCH = c(127.55, 142.33, 127.19, 
86.64, 144.36, 155.95)), .Names = c("TILLER1", "LAI1", "CHLOR1", 
"HEIGHT1", "DIAM1", "NDRE1", "NDVI1", "TCH"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: In `rpd = sd(dat[, which(colnames(dat) == "TCH")][[1]]) / rmse(residuals(reg))`, you try to calculate the standard deviation for a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here you go. Firstly, I've fixed two errors in your code:

In

```
rpd = sd(dat[, which(colnames(dat) == "TCH")][[1]]) / rmse(residuals(reg))
```

you try to calculate the standard deviation for a single value, which returns `NA`. I've removed the `[[1]]` to correct this.

In

```
tmp = data.frame(variable = names(dat[,i]), r2 = summary(reg)$r.squared, 
           mean_error = mean.error, rmse = rmse(residuals(reg)), rpd = rpd)
```

the `names(dat[,i])` returns `NULL`, I've changed it to `names(dat)[i]`.

Then I wrapped your code in a function:

```
foo <- function(dat){

  for (i in 3:(ncol(dat)-1)) {

   ## Train control
   fitControl <- trainControl (
     method = "repeatedcv",
     number = 10,
     savePredictions = "final")

   ## Creating all models
   set.seed(62433)
   reg = train(TCH ~ ., data = dat[, c(i, which(colnames(dat) == "TCH"))], 
          method = 'lm', 
          trControl = fitControl, 
          verbose = TRUE,
          importance = TRUE)

   mean.error = mean(dat$TCH - data.frame(reg$pred$pred)[, 1])

   rpd = sd(dat[, which(colnames(dat) == "TCH")]) / rmse(residuals(reg))

   tmp = data.frame(variable = names(dat)[i], r2 = summary(reg)$r.squared, 
               mean_error = mean.error, rmse = rmse(residuals(reg)), rpd = rpd)

   if (is.null(tabel)) {
     tabel = tmp
   } else {
     tabel = rbind(tabel, tmp)
   }

 }

 return(tabel)
}
```

Now you can put your dataframes in a list, `lapply` the function `foo` over the list, and afterwards `rbind` the tables within the output together:

```
dat <- structure(list(TILLER1 = c(43, 23, 46, 30, 30, 45), 
                      LAI1 = c(3.545, 1.5, 1.76, 1.92, 1.36, 1.27), 
                      CHLOR1 = c(447.2, 432.8, 457.6, 449, 486.8, 455), 
                      HEIGHT1 = c(34.8, 31.5, 26.1, 26, 40.5, 35.2 ), 
                      DIAM1 = c(25.23, 23.9, 21.97, 20.99, 23.92, 24.01), 
                      NDRE1 = c(0.2579, 0.1911, 0.1643, 0.2072, 0.2233, 0.2009), 
                      NDVI1 = c(0.6495, 0.4502, 0.3643, 0.4904, 0.5625, 0.4725), 
                      TCH = c(127.55, 142.33, 127.19, 86.64, 144.36, 155.95)), 
                      .Names = c("TILLER1", "LAI1", "CHLOR1", "HEIGHT1", "DIAM1", "NDRE1", "NDVI1", "TCH"), 
                      row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

dat2 <- dat-1
dat3 <- dat-2
dat4 <- dat-3

datlist <- list(dat, dat2, dat3, dat4)
tablist <- lapply(datlist, foo)
tabel <- do.call(rbind, tablist)
```

The output for my example looks like this:

```
> tab
   variable           r2 mean_error     rmse      rpd
1    CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
2   HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
3     DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
4     NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
5     NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
6    CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
7   HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
8     DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
9     NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
10    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
11   CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
12  HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
13    DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
14    NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
15    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
16   CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
17  HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
18    DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
19    NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
20    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
21   CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
22  HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
23    DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
24    NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
25    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
26   CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
27  HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
28    DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
29    NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
30    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
31   CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
32  HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
33    DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
34    NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
35    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
36   CHLOR1 4.425334e-02  4.8136686 21.57771 1.120519
37  HEIGHT1 4.652398e-01 -2.8263214 16.14037 1.497998
38    DIAM1 5.070381e-01 -6.2447449 15.49675 1.560213
39    NDRE1 1.263715e-03 -0.9279537 22.05766 1.096138
40    NDVI1 4.842547e-07 -0.8747074 22.07160 1.095445
```

Comment: We are almost there. My data sets are like this:

> colnames(dat1)
[1] "TILLER1" "LAI1"    "CHLOR1"  "HEIGHT1" "DIAM1"   "NDRE1"   "NDVI1"   "TCH"     
> colnames(dat2)
[1] "TILLER2" "LAI2"    "CHLOR2"  "HEIGHT2" "DIAM2"   "NDRE2"   "NDVI2"   "TCH"
> colnames(dat3)
[1] "TILLER3" "LAI3"    "CHLOR3"  "HEIGHT3" "DIAM3"   "NDRE3"   "NDVI3"   "TCH"
> colnames(dat4)
[1] "TILLER4" "CHLOR4"  "HEIGHT4" "DIAM4"   "TCH"

So I want to do 4 multiple linear regression to compare the models.
The output I want is a table with the following columns:

dataset, r2, mean_error, rmse, rpd

Comment: Well, when you do the stuff in the answer with your own data, it should look exactly like that. I was just too lazy to change the colnames in the example data. Have you tried it with your own data already?

Comment: Yes, it worked here. But the output it's a table with the parameters for every variable. Actually I need a table of only 4 rows, each row corresponding to one dataset/model(multiple linear regression)

Comment: Well, what formula should be used for the multiple regression? Are there any interactions or should all predictors be included equally?

Comment: I need to create 1 multiple linear regression model for each dataset, and then I want to create a table to compare them according to their RMSE, r², RPD and Mean Error. The formula is the same as the script